# How to deal with "Leave site? Changes may not be saved." pop-ups in google chrome using Selenium w/ Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I'm building an automated Python script using Selenium that needs to open a new url to work properly, and whenever I leave a specific url, my program is met with a "Leave site? Changes may not be saved." popup from chrome.

The script is a Python script utilizing Selenium.

I'm using Chrome and the ChromeDriver for web navigation.

The actual issue occurs after I use XPATH to click a button on the webpage that redirects to a different page. The script pauses for a second, then closes the browser window and displays an error message.

The error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/giterdone.py", line 222, in <module>
    giterdone()
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/giterdone.py", line 178, in giterdone
    makerepo()
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/giterdone.py", line 165, in makerepo
    writefiles(ier)
  File "/Users/myname/Desktop/giterdone.py", line 142, in writefiles
    element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="repo-content-pjax-container"]/react-app/div/div/div[1]/div/div/main/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/span[2]/input')
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 739, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 228, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)  # type: ignore[call-arg]  # mypy is not smart enough here
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: {Alert text : 
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : }
  (Session info: chrome=117.0.5938.132)
```

I'm relatively new to Python and can't figure out how to get the script to get past this popup without user input. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: driver.switch_to.alert.accept() probably if it's an alert.

Comment: Arundeep, could you elaborate on that?